# Graph of given degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to have a graph with vertices of degrees: 1, 1, 2, 3, 3?
How do we tackle such questions?

Comment: "How do we tackle such questions?" Trial and error, mostly. As long as the sequence obeys the handshaking lemma, there's not much else to do, I think.

Comment: This might help : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence

Comment: @maverick This should answer your question : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphicSequence.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not completely empty handed.

Sanity checks:

- If a sequence has a number greater than $n-1$, where $n$ is the number of coordinates (vertices), then it cannot be constructed (as there's not enough vertices to form the neighbors).
- If a sequence sums to an odd number, it would violate the [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), and can't be constructed.
- If there's a lot of vertices of degree $1$, and two or more vertices of high degree, sometimes this can make it impossible (if we were to attempt to create one, we'd end up with too many vertices of degree $2$ or more).

Proving existence:

- We can check if such a graph exists using the [Erdős-Gallai Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem).

Construct example:

- We can construct an example of such a graph using the [Havel-Hakimi Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm).

Construct all non-isomorphic examples:

- I tend to just use `geng` (which comes with Nauty), with the command line `geng n e:e` where $n$ is the number of vertices (in this case 5) and $e$ is the number of edges (in this case $\tfrac{1}{2}(1+1+2+3+3)=5$).  Afterwards, I filter out the ones which don't have the degree sequence using a [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) script.

In this example, there is a unique graph (with vertices marked with their degree):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Mostly try and error. What I learned so far is that there are no *good* characterizations of degree sequences.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you allow loops and parallel edges then the problem is very simple: just draw 5 nodes and $1+1+2+3+3=10$ edge ends, then join the edge ends whichever way you like. This is possible as $10$ is even (if the total were odd it would be impossible).
[image]